# Unexpected keyword or identifier.ts(1434)

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, typeerror, node.js-fs

I have the following code that tries to read a file from the local machine and upload it to the AWS s3 cloud service:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import fs, { ReadStream } from "fs";
import path from "path";

class Uploads {

  static const bucketName = "myappllbuck";
  static const s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
  static const filePath = "/home/s/img2.png";

  static const uploadParams: {
    Bucket: string;
    Key: string;
    Body: string | ReadStream;
    ContentType: any; ACL: string
  } = {
      Bucket: this.bucketName,
      Key: '',
      Body: '',
      ContentType: null,
      ACL: 'public-read',
    };

  static const fileStream  = fs.createReadStream(this.filePath);

  
  fileStream.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('File Error', err);
  });
   this.uploadParams.Body = this.fileStream;
   this.uploadParams.Key = path.basename(filePath);
   this.uploadParams.ContentType = 'image/png';
   this.uploadParams.ACL = 'public-read';
}
```

But I get the following error @`fileStream.on()` line:

```
Unexpected keyword or identifier.ts(1434)
Member 'fileStream' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7008)
```

And the following error @`this.UploadParams.` lines of the code:

```
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code starting from `fileStream.on('error', function(err) {` is still inside the class. Make sure to close the class declaration before running this code.

Comment: You say this function shouldn't be inside the class?

Comment: @best_of_man The function can be inside this class, but you got instructions under it. Classes can't have side effects code hanging around like that :)